# A couple of heroku postgres questions (just started, am lost)

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have provisioned postgres on my heroku app and also installed postgres locally to maintain parity (as the documentation recommends) with the online database but I'm also not understanding how this will work. Am I supposed to be accessing a local copy of a database when running on my own computer (while building and before deploying) and then using heroku's separate postgres database once it is deployed? If it is parity, shouldn't they both be using the heroku postgres database?

In other words, will my local app (during production) and heroku app (deployed and live) be using the same online postgres database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I supposed to be accessing a local copy of a database when running on my own computer (while building and before deploying) and then using heroku's separate postgres database once it is deployed?

Yes, that's exactly it. Without seeing what bit of documentation you're referencing it's hard to say what they mean but perhaps there's another way to explain it.

In your local development environment, you may find that you need to test database schema changes (this is just one example, there are many). If you only had the one heroku postgres database you'd be forced to test these changes in production, which might result in poor usability for your users and that doesn't even account for the possibility of making a mistake and accidentally destroying your production data. There are a number of other shortcomings and challenges with this single database configuration.

For these reasons and more, it's best to keep your production data completely separated from your development/staging/test environment by creating a local/staging database. You might reasonably ask, "What about the data? I need data to test!". There are many ways to put together your test database and which you choose will likely depend on your needs. A shortlist of possibilities:

- Use a seed file to generate mock data in your db
- Use a model factory (usually runs in conjunction with your testing framework)
- Take a dump of your production database, anonymize and redact sensitive information and use that for local testing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was thinking they wanted local and production to be the same which was confusing me. Either way, it's up and going. Thanks.